# Ruby on Rails & Remote MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-connection

I am a beginner in developing rails application and I am trying to import data from the remote MySQL database (from my other machine). So my question is, Is it possible to access/import the data from remote MySQL server on a button click in a locally hosted rails app ?

Thank you

Edit: 
My aim is to show a selected fields of data in a locally hosted rails app from a remote MySQL database. I want the view of the respective rails page to be changed with the receiving SQL output after a button is clicked.

Comment: Have you even tried searching a bit on Google on this prior to sending it to SO?

Comment: Yes, I did. But couldn't able to find a proper info about my question. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, of course.

Basically, you have two ways of doing this.

The import/export way and the programmer's way.

**Programmer's way** (not recommended, in my humble opinion):

Assuming you build your application in a way that can access the data in your remote db, you should do two things:

I. Make your remote DB accessible from the server you're working on.  There are many posts available on how to do that, either by a)using PHPMyadmin or b)directly, commandline, from your remote server.

For instance, respectively:

a) Select your DB in PHPMyAdmin, go to privileges and add an entry for your remote access.

b) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';` and then restart your dbserver

II. In your rails app, assuming you already work with another db, you should probably do something like this:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

**Import/Export**

Anyhow, I would go to export/import... And I would chose the CSV way.... RoR is magically simple for importing csv data. It is easy to import CSV data, apply some transforms to make it compatible to your model and save to your new DB.

This railscast shows how to import data from csv files.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

Comment: Thank you, Stavros Souvatzis. I want to do the programmer's way as I want to import the live data in to the rails page on a button click. I have already seen the import/export screencasts from the railscasts before posting this question, and decided not to do that way. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped.